# What does the phrase "know no bounds" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I am trying to get the meaning for the word *vitriol* from a dictionary. It gives this sentence as an example.

> The vitriol he hurled at members of the press knew no bounds.

I understand the main parts of the sentence is **'The vitriol knew no bounds'**. But how 'the vitriol' could 'knew' something? The subject for 'knew' should be a person. Am I getting it right?

Comment: knew no bounds --> knew no limits --> was unlimited  - See [*to know no bounds*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-know-no-bounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/know%20no%20bounds/boundaries), "know no bounds" means:
>

> > 1 : to be capable of affecting people of everywhere
> >
> > 2 : to have no limits

So, in short, "know no bounds" means to have no limits.

Comment: Is this phrase "know no bounds"  commonly used?

Comment: @dan, no it isn't exactly common in the US, however it may be used more in other countries.